# In Java, can you change/set the value of the variable in a for loop?

Tags: java

My apologies in advance if my terminology is incorrect.

In Java, if I have a for loop of the form:

```
    Entry something_else = ....;
    for (Entry x : entries) {
        x = something_else;
    }
```

is it kosher/ok to set that loop variable (x) to something_else inside the body of the for loop as above?

Comment: Do you expect changing `x` in this way to also change the value in `entries` that it was originally populated from?

Comment: ...which is to say: Whether this is "kosher" is a matter of style; but whether it actually _accomplishes your goal_ requires us to tell us what your expectations are.

Comment: Changing the variable that you're iterating on is a source of inadvertant errors and if I saw this done intentionally in code, I would have an issue with it. It's certainly not common. What is it you *want* to do? There is likely another way to do it.

Comment: Hi - I ran into this in some code that was written previously by someone else, when I was (am) debugging a problem, and I thought that it was odd, so by "kosher/ok", I was wondering if it would somehow cause the for loop logic to not behave as-expected.

Comment: Charles Duffy - actually you "hit the nail on the head" - what you said is actually what I am wondering MIGHT happen?  Is that even possible?  This code was inside a method and that 'entries' var was the argument of the method and in the code I am looking at, it looks like the 'entries' WAS changed by SOMETHING.  I don't know what that 'something' is, but one of the only explanations I have is if the 'entries' was changed inadverdently by/inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

This code is absolutely equivalent to:

```
Entry something_else = ....;
for (Entry y : entries) {
    Entry x = y; // a copy of the reference to that object
    x = something_else; // has no effect whatsoever on y
}
```

Otherwise, it works.

So this code may do something *surprising*, which may not be what the author meant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but not a good idea.

It makes much more sense to just create another variable and give it the newly desired value, eliminating any possible confusion.

I can't think of a scenario where doing this adds clarity or any other benefit. Maybe you have an example?